# Is it possible to know when a file was deleted from an iCloud folder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, icloud, cloud-storage

I'm writing a file sync framework and am dealing with the peculiarities of iCloud right now.

Basically I'd like to know if a file was deleted from iCloud so that when my device syncs with it, it will not try to upload the local copy because actually you need to delete the local copy.

So, when listing the contents of my ubiquity container, is there a way to show deleted files and get their deletedAt `Date`?  (Or conversely, list the contents of the deleted folder, if iOS allows that at application level)